# Array sum in mongo db with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Array sum in mongo db in PHP

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 4fcf2f2313cfcd344500000d
)
[id] => 14
[name] => Aryan Roban
[score] => Array (
    [03-06-2012] => 2
    [04-06-2012] => 3
    [05-06-2012] => 5
    [06-06-2012] => 4
)
```

I need to array sum(total) of score array, so that

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 4fcf2f2313cfcd2454500000d
)
[id] => 14
[type] => Football
[score] => Array (
    [03-06-2012] => 2
    [04-06-2012] => 3
    [05-06-2012] => 5
    [06-06-2012] => 4
)
[total] => 14
```

This want to done for every records where type is Football.

How it can be done ?

Comment: In database this can be done with [map-reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce). Read the docs.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev: Can you please give me a demo how mongo map-reduce works in php ?

Comment: There are code samples in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
function addElements( &$v, $k ) {
    $v[ 'total' ] = array_sum( $v[ 'score' ] );
}

$arr = array(
    0 => array('id' => 14,'name' => 'Aryan Roban','score' => array ('03-06-2012' => 2,'04-06-2012' => 3,'05-06-2012' => 5,'06-06-2012' => 4)),
    1 => array('id' => 5,'name' => 'Test','score' => array ('03-06-2012' => 2,'04-06-2012' => 1,'05-06-2012' => 15,'06-06-2012' => 8))
);

array_walk( $arr, 'addElements' );
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Hope this helps.